# Wrong section ref in the header with leftmark, twocolumn article

Tags: header-footer, two-column

I am trying to make a reference to the leftmark (last defined title) in header of a twocolumn article. The reference though keeps refering to the rightmark (last defined title. I have included the latex bug fixer package (`\usepackage{fixltx2e}`) and this did not help the problem.

I have searched high and low for an old answer that could fix my problem, so I hope someone knows the answer.

Here is an example with the nessesary part of my code to illustrate my problem[image: Here is a picture of the file generated from my code, of the page that illustrates the problem.]:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

% HEADER AND FOOTERS %

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[RO,RE]{\small\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[RO,RE]{\bfseries \thepage / \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyfoot[RO,RE]{\bfseries \thepage / \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.02pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\rhead{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
%
\newlength\FHleft \setlength\FHleft{13cm}
\newlength\FHright \setlength\FHright{0cm}
\newbox\FHline
\setbox\FHline=\hbox{\hsize=\paperwidth
    \hspace*{\FHleft}
    \rule{\dimexpr\headwidth-\FHleft-\FHright\relax}{\headrulewidth}\hspace*{\FHright}}
\renewcommand\headrule{\vskip-.7\baselineskip\copy\FHline}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % 
    \fancyfoot[R]{\bfseries \thepage / \pageref{LastPage}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Test1}
\lipsum[1-8]

\section{Test2}
\lipsum[6]

\section{Test3}
\lipsum[7]

\section{Test4}
\lipsum[8]

\section{Test5}
\lipsum[9]

\end{document}
```

I hope i did this right - first time :)

Comment: `\leftmark` refers to the last `\section` title on the page (in the `article` class`), whereas `\rightmark` refers to the first `\subsection` title`. And `fixltx2e` is obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first section title of the page in your header, there are two possibilities. (1) if you don't need the subsection titles in your headers or footers, you can use

```
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\renewcommand\subsectionmark[1]{}
```

and then use `\rightmark` instead of `\leftmark`.

The second possibility, that leaves the subsction titles still available is to use:

```
\usepackage{extramarks}
```

and then use `\firstleftmark` instead of `\leftmark`. However, this may occasionally leave the last section title of the previous page in the title (actually this would be the section title of the first text of the page, which then still belongs to the last section on the previous page). This would happen if there was a subsection on that page before the first section.

Comment: Thank you so much. The second option works perfectly. The first though makes reference to the first title in the second column, even tough i have the latex bug fixer package. Just for reference, if others has the same problem.